# Command runs in discord.py, but does not send embed and gives no error

Tags: python, discord.py

I ran into a strange problem on discord.py where. The rest of it works, but it does not reply with my embed with no errors.
This is the code that wont work:

```
#The code if the number is incorrect
print(arg1)
    placement = sessions.index(ctx.author.id)
    placement = +1
    if arg1 != str(sessions[placement]):
      if int(arg1) >= sessions[placement]:
       print(sessions)
       placement = sessions.index(ctx.author.id)
       placement = +2
       print(sessions)
       embed=discord.Embed(title="Incorrect", description=f"Your number is too big, you have {str(sessions[placement])} left.", color=0xFF5733)
       embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://simg.nicepng.com/png/small/255-2554736_cancel-cliparts-red-x-transparent.png")
       await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
      else:
        placement = sessions.index(ctx.author.id)
        placement = +2
        print(sessions)
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Incorrect", description=f"Your number is too small you have {str(sessions[placement])} left.", color=0xFF5733)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://simg.nicepng.com/png/small/255-2554736_cancel-cliparts-red-x-transparent.png")
        await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
```

The functions run but the embeds will not send and no error is being logged.

Im trying to create a random number guessing game bot that generates random sessions for individual users to guess a number. But I discovered that for some reason it will not reply with the embed.
I tried renaming it, but it still did not work, I changed it to discord.embed but still does not work. I do not know what is causing this.
Just to note, the rest of the command does work and so does the code except for sending the embed.
I don't know why its these two embeds individually, but the rest of the messages send.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try `Ctx.send` or `Ctx.message.reply`
I use `Colour` name in embeds try to change that too

Comment: This does not really help, I found out its no a property affecting it

Comment: So Check Conditions